# Not Connected to Google drive with cloudrail library xamarin.ios

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, google-drive-api, cloudrail

I am using CloudRail Library to connect with google drive in xamarin forms. In xamarin.android it working perfectly buy in xamarin.ios it is not working.
anyone can help me ?

thanks

Comment: Post some code to get idea

Answer (score 0):

We (Cloudrail) are having issue with Google Drive for Xamarin.iOS, we hope to fix this issue this week.